# Redshift: SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Database my_db not found

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I create a database in redshift like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
```

Then my schema:

```
create external schema ext_my_db
    from
    database 'my_db'
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/RedshiftSpectrum';
```

Then I create a table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext_my_db.test (
 "int" bigint)
location
  's3://my_bucket/etc/';
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Database my_db not found.
```

What am I overlooking here?

EDIT: I'm making the connection with the DBeaver client

Answer (score 0):

I updated the schema as follows:

```
create external schema ext_gbq_google_ads
    from data catalog
    database 'ext_gbq_google_ads'
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::496351116919:role/RedshiftSpectrum'
    create external database if not exists;
```

And this did the trick.